# C# winform and gecko how to view page with pdf files

Tags: c#, gecko

I am able to use the gecko web browser on my `winform` but some of the page have `pdf` files and cannot be display on my `winform` is there any additional parameters to add on initialization or is this possible using `Gecko`?

```
 public partial class web : Form
    {
        public web()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
             geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/main/");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Adobe Acrobat Reader on the server you're working on. You'll be able to display pdf files on browsers.